# How do I overwrite a bitbake conf which references an include

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

I have an openembedded build for some custom hardware that has a BSP layer. When I build, BSP layer throws an error because the size of one of the file systems is too large. I found this issue in my (names deliberately changed)

```
meta-my-bsp/conf/machine/machineA.conf
```

In machineA.conf, there's a line:

```
require conf/machine/include/machineA.inc
```

In machineA.inc is the value I need to change to resize my filesystem to make it the right size. When I edit this directly in the meta-my-bsp layer, this compiles and creates the filesystem correctly.

Now, I need to put it into meta-my-layer which is has a higher value than the BSP layer (overrides the BSP layer recipes). So I copied the files into my layer.

```
meta-my-layer/conf/machine/include/machineA.inc <--- Modified with the value I need
meta-my-layer/conf/machine/machineA.conf (No modifications)
```

However, when I rebuild everything, it doesn't look like my machineA.inc is getting picked up. Is this the right way to go about it, or am I missing something? I can pull in the whole meta-my-bsp conf and recipes into meta-my-layer, but that seems totally overkill and a bad design. What is the proper way to override this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

To use the *machineA.inc* from *meta-my-layer* you should do

```
    require ${COREBASE}/meta-my-layer/conf/machine/include/machineA.inc
```